# .htaccess redirecting URL but not content for subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I'm trying to set up a test site but having real trouble getting `.htaccess` to redirect properly.

I want the contents of `www.example.com/test` to show when a user types in test.example.com. My rewrite rules allow me to use `test.example.com` in the address bar, but it's actually showing me the content of the root (`www.example.com`), not the `test` subfolder.

I'm not an `.htaccess` guru by any stretch, but I've been using Stack Overflow for 5 years and this is the first time I've been stumped enough to ask a question! Your collective wisdom is appreciated.

Here's the relevant part of my `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite for http cases
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# Rewrite for no www cases
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www\.example\.com [NC]

#redirect for test subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect to correct for old subfolder usage
RewriteRule ^oldsubfolder/$ https://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the contents of `www.example.com/test` to show when a user types in `test.site.com`.

I assume you just have one domain and `test.site.com` should really be `test.example.com` (which would seem to be consistent with the rest of your question)?

In the code you've posted, there's nothing that really attempts to do this redirect? In the code you've posted, a request for `test.example.com` would not be redirected - so if it is then you may be seeing a cached response. Clear your browser cache.

You would need something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(test)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/%1/$1 [R,L]
```

The `(?:www\.)?` part simply catches an optional `www` subdomain of the subdomain! Depending on how this subdomain was created, both `test.example.com` and `www.test.example.com` might be accessible. (Although I suspect your SSL cert probably doesn't allow this anyway?)

`%1` is a backreference to the captured group in the `CondPattern` (ie. `test`) and `$1` is a backreference to the captured `RewriteRule` *pattern*. Capturing the subdomain (eg. "test") just avoids repetition, but also allows for more than one subdomain to be handled by the same rule.

This is also a temporary (302) redirect. Change this to a 301 only when you are sure it's working (if that is the intention). 301s are cached by default, so can make testing problematic.

Clear your browser cache before testing.

---

> ```
> # Rewrite for no www cases
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www\.example\.com [NC]
>
> #redirect for test subdomain
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test\.example\.com$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

The comment in the middle of this block would seem to be misleading (it doesn't "redirect for test subdomain"). The whole block just redirects to www, excluding the `test` subdomain. The other code then redirects the subdomain.

---

**UPDATE:**

> I was hoping it would continue to show test.example.com in the address bar

Yes, this is possible. Providing `test.example.com` and `www.example.com` point to the same filesystem then you can simply *rewrite* the request without actually changing the host. For this example, I'll assume `test.example.com` and `www.example.com` point to the same document root.

Change the above *redirect* to the following *rewrite*:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(test)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /%1/$1 [L]
```

The request now stays on `test.example.com` and will serve content from `test.example.com/test` (although this is hidden from the user) since `test.example.com` and `www.example.com` are really the same thing.

The check against `REDIRECT_STATUS` ensures we are only processing the intial request and not the rewritten request, thus avoiding a rewrite loop. `REDIRECT_STATUS` is empty on the initial request and set to `200` after the first successful rewrite.

However, if `test.example.com` points somewhere entirely different then you'll need to implement a reverse proxy and "proxy" the request to `www.example.com` in order to "hide" this from the user.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. I'll try this out. I that the code might not be redirecting to the subdomain, but as I create the subdomain through my webhost I figured it was handling the redirection outside of .htaccess. At least that's how it worked when I did it previously.

Comment: That seems to have worked. I was hoping it would continue to show test.example.com in the address bar - it now just directs me to www.example.com/test - but that's not a big deal. It works! Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can still show `test.example.com` in the address bar. If the subdomain points to the same area of the filesystem as the main domain then you can implement an _internal rewrite_ instead of an _external redirect_. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much for this. Took me a couple of days to get this working properly, but your advice was spot on. There were some weird conflicts between how my host handles redirects and how my .htaccess file was set up. Knowing how it should be done and that it COULD be done was a huge help.